# Centering Item CSS

Tags: css, center, margin

I'm trying to center some text that is styled and I applied margin:auto, but I'm not getting the results I need. Any thoughts?

```
.cd-timeline-content .timeline-date {
  margin:0 auto;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-top:0.5em;
  opacity:0.7;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: The element that the text is in must have `display:block` or `display:inline-block` with a width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to tell without markup, but here's a few pointers.

In order to used `margin: 0 auto;` you must also supply a width. In order for a width to work the element must be a block level element. That means, set to `display: inline-block;` or `display: block;`.